# JavaScript target data on child element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am working on an audio player based on JavaScript. I am trying to make a playlist for the audio player and I succeeded with select and option (html), however I can't style those. So I tried with an ul and li.

So I have the HTML markup:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li data="Another_Song" class="songs_wrap">
        <div class="songs_inner">
            <h4>Song #1</h4>
            <p>Some song details</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function initAudioPlayer() {
    var audio, dir, ext, mylist, mylist_li;

    ext = ".mp3";
    dir = "audio/";

    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = dir+"My_Song"+ext;
    audio.loop = false;

    //Object ref
    mylist = document.getElementById("mylist");
    mylist_li = mylist.getElementsByTagName("li"); //targeting the li elements

    //Event handling
    mylist.addEventListener("change", changeTrack);
    mylist_li.addEventListener("click", doSomethingElse); //not sure about what it should do in corelation with the changetrack function i already have on the event.

    //Functions
    function changeTrack(event){
        audio.src = dir+event.target.data+ext;
        audio.play();
    }

}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

Now when I click the li, the song should change to audio/Another_Song.mp3 , but it doesn't. I believe what I am doing wrong is targeting the "data" from the li.

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: there is no `change` event on lists.

Comment: Can you post complete HTML? I mean `li` don't have anything inside?

Comment: _when I click the li, the song should change_. There's nothing in your code handling `click events`.

Comment: Oh, ok. So instead of "change" i should use "click"

Comment: @SimeriaIonut: Start by handling click on `li`. Then go on to use event delegation on `ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should handle song selection in your case. Note that you must listen `onclick` event and select event target properly:

```
//Event handling
mylist.addEventListener("click", changeTrack);

//Functions
function changeTrack(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    while (target !== mylist) {
        if (target.nodeName == 'LI') {
            audio.src = dir + target.getAttribute('data') + ext;
            audio.play();
        }
        target = target.parentNode
    }
}
```

Note the `while` loop. It' very important to realized that click event will originally happen on some nested element (not `li`). It means that `event.target` will be for example `H4` or `P` element, not `LI` as you expect. So you have to walk up the DOM tree until you find closest `LI` node.

Finally you should use `getAttribute` method to read attribute `data`, since there is no such property as `data`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6fryqatq/

Comment: That worked for me. Now i even understand why it was not working before, thanks a lot for the explanation.